# How to save current time or date

Tags: java, android

How can I save the current time and date,I just want the date and time of the last time that I entered that activity

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    CardView cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view2);
     textView = view.findViewById(R.id.dateTv);
     SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            mydate = getPrefs.getString("Test","");
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
            Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
            mydate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            textView.setText(mydate);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("Test", mydate);
    editor.apply();
}
```

when i restart the app, it doesnt work

Comment: "it doesnt work" isnt a working problem description. Do you get an error log, an unexpected value, ... so please se [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: And note that the Calendar APIs are like 1999. Avoid using that stuff.

Comment: i'm sorry sir,im still beginner and new user here...

Comment: I didn't get an error message. but the date/time its working fine,when i restart the app ,the time empty again

Comment: Post these important details as edits to your Question, rather than as Comments.

Comment: Your prose says you want to track when the user enters the activity. But your code says you want to track when user clicks button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

Latter you have to convert milliseconds to date and time.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("Test", System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
    editor.apply();
}
```

Here is the code to convert milliseconds to date and time.

```
public static String getDateTime(String milli) {
        long milliSeconds = Long.parseLong(milli);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy',' hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);

        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-date classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java-time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 0):

## Lifecycle

You commented:

> I didn't get an error message. but the date/time its working fine,when i restart the app ,the time empty again

I don’t know Android, so these are just wild guesses…

(A) I do not see where you display the moment upon launch of the app. Looks to me like you retrieve the stored value, but do not display it. Shouldn’t your `onViewCreated` call `textView.setText(mydate);`?

(B) Write the moment to storage immediately upon its capture. That is, within your `onClick` handler.

I looked briefly at the [method doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()), and the [lifecycle doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). It is not clear to me whether or not the user can exit your activity without necessarily firing the `onPause` event.

## Avoid legacy classes

Your question’s code uses terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.

## `Instant`

To capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

For storage, logging, and data-exchange, generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.now() ;
```

> 2022-01-23T15:30:45.786347Z

That ISO 8691 string is what you should be writing to storage.

When retrieving from storage, recreate the `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( textRetrievedFromStorage ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To present to the user, adjust to their expected/desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Alternatively, use the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

When presenting to user, you way want to lop off the fractional second.

```
zdt = zdt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

For your user-interface, generate text while automatically localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault() ; // Or specify, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Comment: oh thanks for your help sir!,its almost done

Comment: @CharlieBrown Good. Please go back and edit your Question for clarity and details, as requested in the Comments.